# AWS API Gateway, lambda function with path parameter in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, path-variables

Does someone have an example of an API Gateway lambda function that receives a path parameter, that is written in python?  Every example I can find is written in javascript, and doesn't quite connect for me.

Here's what I mean:  from my-template.yaml:

```
Events:
  Call:
    Type: Api
    Properties:
      Path: /blast-jobs/{id}
      Method: get
```

I'm not getting something named "id" in my event, what should I be expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The event your Lambda receives contains a field called `pathParameters`.

This python Lambda:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event['pathParameters'])
```

prints out:

```
{'id': '987654'}
```

when this URL is invoked

`<gateway_invoke_url>/Prod/blast-jobs/987654`

Comment: Please, where is that documented? I was having a really hard time finding it.

Comment: I didn't find it in documentation, I just tested it.